# What possible characters may returned as a result from PHP's uniqid()?

Tags: php

What  possible characters may contained result from  function uniqid() ? as I understood, this is only alphanumeric characters, but need confirm from you. So, this is so?

P.S. In documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php I dont see info about this

Comment: If you need to limit the possible character range, you could eg. base64 encode the result.

Comment: No, I just need that obtain from this function inuque id, which not contained nothing, except alphanumerics, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the comments of the same documentation page : "As others below note, without prefix and without "added entropy", this function simply returns the UNIX timestamp with added microsecond counter as a hex number; it's more or less just microtime(), in hexit form."

So it returns only hexadecimal characters, e.g. 0-9 a-f.

Edit: As Vulcan pointed out in the comments below: `$more_entropy`, when true, appends a period and some 0-9 characters.

Comment: `$more_entropy`, when true, appends a period and some 0-9 characters.